# Javascript refresh array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am using ajax to call DB and using DOM to create the HTML for a small weather widget.

So I have an Array of element called _weather.

Its populate fine, however I am having touble to refresh the data in the array.

I have a button that if clicked call this function and pass the city name _town

My idea is to remove the value from array and call the function _checkNewTown to display the city I just removed from the array.

```
var _update_city = function(_town){

    ntown = _town;
    town = _town;

    _weather.prototype.removeByValue = function (town) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            var c = this[i];
            if (c == town || (town.equals && town.equals(c))) {
                this.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    _checkNewTown(ntown);

}
```

However its not working and its returning

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'removeByValue': object is null or undefined 
weather_widget.js, line 121 character 3
```

I tried change it but could not figure out what to use.

Any help will be apprecciated

Comment: Not clear on the exact procedures, but it looks like you are declaring the prototype's property "removeByValue" inside a function _update_city, however, the function removeByValue() is never invoked. What's on the line 121?

Comment: `_weather.prototype.removeByValue = function (town) {` this is on line 121.

Comment: Try to declare the prototype definition outside of the function, and be sure that the array _weather has been initialized prior. Also, you will need to invoke the function "removeByValue()" after as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the array is initialized inside the ajax call, it  won't be visible unless the call has been made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove items from an array like so:

```
var weather = [{city: 'city1', ....}, ....];
var city = 'city1';

var filtered = weather.filter(function (i) {
  return i.city !== city;
});
```